# Animate/Translate the View from behind another View

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-animation

I do not know wether it should be called `translate` or `animate`.

I have a Framelayout , starting from the top of Activity, and it ends up about the center or new center of the screen.

This FrameLayout has two images in it.
But I do not bother about them.

Now I have another RelaytiveLayout which has two Views: a TextView and a Button.

I want that, at specific time, they start animating/translating downward from the end of the FrameLayout and get their original height, which should be the height of the TextView and the Button.

I do not want to give fixed sizes, therefore I can not give fixed x,y pixel coordinates to translate.

Here it is my xml layout

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/main_frame">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/animationboard"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_animation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:contentDescription="animation"
    android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"


    />

</FrameLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main_frame"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/secondry_frame">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Anggor"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Close"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/close"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see, I set the TextView and Button visibility to gone, so that when I translate those Views they should be set visible.

I have no idea on how to do that.
Please help.

Comment: What are you trying to move? the FrameLayout, or the RelativeLayout? Or Both? What exactly are you trying to do with the sizes? Do you want to animate only the position, or also the size? Please try to be as clear as you possibly can about this, maybe with an illustration (image) of what you're trying to do (as in - before & after images).

Comment: I am trying to move down the relativelayout from the point the framelayout ends , so it would give illusion that its coming down from the end of the framelayout , the framelayout would not move however.

Answer (score 1):

I have done it my self , just sharing the answer so that if any one want it any time later. What I have done to achieve  is a illusion , I have set my Relativelayout(which needs to be move) behind the Framelayout(which contains images) 
so now my xml part looks like this,

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

    android:clipChildren="false">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main_frame"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/secondry_frame"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:background="#ffaaff">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Anor"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:visibility="gone"

            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Close"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/close"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/main_frame"
    android:clipChildren="false">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/animationboard"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</FrameLayout>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_animation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:contentDescription="animation"
    android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So by doing this , my Relative layout is covered by the Framelayout images.

Now the second trick was to start the animation from the middle of screen , so that no one can see the animation is starting from the top as the images has cover the middle part of the screen , here is what I have made my animation file and placed it in the anim folder

**animfalling**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="-50%p"
        android:toYDelta="0"
        android:duration="2000"/>
</set>
```

and thus I used in my java code like

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.secondry_frame);
                final Animation animationFalling = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(c, R.anim.anim_falling);
                rl.startAnimation(animationFalling);
```

and its giving me the result I was looking for :)